# JavaScript: How to filter array by values nested in object 2 level deep

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects.

Within each object of the array, there can be multiple "Book" objects, all with dynamic keys. I want the objects with at least one "Book" object that is new.

For example:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: '123',
    book1242: {isNew: true},
    book9023: {isNew: false},
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book0374: {isNew: false},
    book9423: {isNew: false},
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book8423: {isNew: false},
    book9023: {isNew: false},
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book6534: {isNew: true},
    book9313: {isNew: false},
  },
]
```

So my filtered array will consist of the first and last element of the original array

Expected filtered array

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: '123',
    book1242: {isNew: true},
    book9023: {isNew: false},
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book6534: {isNew: true},
    book9313: {isNew: false},
  },
]
```

I have tried using `filter` and `map`, but I get to the point where I have to loop through and check which book is new and I'm not sure how to return that object within the filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

`arr.filter((o) => Object.values(o).some((b) => b.isNew))`

Will your array only ever have keys that are `id` and `bookwxyz`? If not you may need to do some checking on the values to make sure they aren't undefined

You could also explicitly check the key using Object.entries and a regular expression:

`arr.filter((o) => Object.entries(o).some(([key, value]) => /book\d{4}/.test(key) && value.isNew))`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Good point, I was trying to find a way to deal with the fact that there might be other things in the array that could contain isNew but that's so unlikely I've changed the answer.

Comment: Beautifully simple. Terrific job!

Comment: PS, to provide more longevity, instead or relying to `4` - I would do `/book\d+$/` so that in *N* years from now I don't need to care about bugs arising just because a library got more books.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#some` with `Object.values`.

```js
const arr = [ { id: '123', book1242: {isNew: true}, book9023: {isNew: false}, }, { id: '123', book0374: {isNew: false}, book9423: {isNew: false}, }, { id: '123', book8423: {isNew: false}, book9023: {isNew: false}, }, { id: '123', book6534: {isNew: true}, book9313: {isNew: false}, }, ];
const res = arr.filter(obj=>Object.values(obj).some(({isNew})=>isNew));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It won't work whenever there is any non-object values, like primitive boolean or float.

Comment: @w35l3y Have you tried it? It does work fine. In fact, the id is a primitive in the example.

Comment: You are right. It won't work with `null` or `undefined` only.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr=[{id:"123",book1242:{isNew:!0},book9023:{isNew:!1}},{id:"123",book0374:{isNew:!1},book9423:{isNew:!1}},{id:"123",book8423:{isNew:!1},book9023:{isNew:!1}},{id:"123",book6534:{isNew:!0},book9313:{isNew:!1}}];

const res = arr.filter(obj => {
  for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)){
    if(key.substring(0,4) === 'book' && val.isNew === true){
      return obj
    }
   }
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is certainly the most explicit and safe one, actually checking the key has `book` at the front. You could replace the for loop with `some`, and filter only requires you to return a boolean so you could just return `key.substring(0,4) === 'book' && val.isNew` directly

Answer (score 0):

```
 let sorted =[]
  arr.forEach((el, i) => {
         let obj_values = Object.values(el);
         obj_values = obj_values.filter((elem) => typeof elem == 'object' && elem.isNew == true);
if(obj_values.length) sorted.push(arr[i])
     })
```